# i have three columns, i want to combine them all in one main_table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i am working in mysql, i know about tables relationships 'joins' etc,
I have three different tables, each table has column id, i want to combine all three ids in one main table, because i want to apply inner join after getting all ids in one table.
can you please tell me how i can get all three ids in one table, i know about foreign key and primary key, but i don't know how i can apply that here... or is there any simple method of doing it.[image]
My tables name:

```
Table 1 contains: student_id coloumn
Table 2 contains: teachers_id
Table 3 contains: class_id
```

Main table is **table 4**: which will have **student_id,teachers_id,class_id coloumn**

i am trying to generate time table, i want get student id,teachers_id and class_id, in main table time_table; i am trying to do normalization so that i don't have to repeat all name again and again, i can just use id to call any class name teacher name subject name etc, all ids are primary keys in tables.

The relationship is one to one in this case

---

i am working on php_mysql.

Thankyou

Comment: Read about [UNION and UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Show sample data, expected result and what you have tried

Comment: what's the relationship between the tables ? is a foreign key exists already ? please provide more details

Comment: If you want to combine those three tables they need to be related to each other. Otherwise you will get a huge table with all IDs of one table for all IDs for all other tables.

Comment: Yea what @GuyL said

Comment: i am trying to generate time table, i want get student id,teachers_id and class_id, in main table time_table; i am trying to do normalization so that i don't have to repeat all name again and again, i can just use id to call any class name teacher name subject name etc, all ids are primary keys in tables.

Comment: in that case you need a relationship from student to class

Comment: plus a relationship between class and teacher. one table for all won't help since it won't represent a proper relation, or over complicate things

Comment: please check updated question.

Comment: If you have ONE teacher for MANY class, ONE class for MANY student, then you should have : one table for teacher, one table for class, one table for student. Then you can have one table teacher / class (if you need to add information between teacher and class like if it's the main teacher for example) or add id_teacher in class table and one table class / student (same, if you need to add details between the relationship between class and student, for example if it's an option for some student or main class I don't know) or add id_class in student table.

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MickaelLeger for now i just want to take all ids in one table, i just want to know  how to do this.

Comment: @iMatt I don't get the question, you want to create a new table with all id? If yes, just create the table with 4 columns (id_new_table, id_student, id_class, id_teacher) and add the data? Or you want a querie to get those 3 information in one row? In this case you need to have relationship between those table

Comment: @MickaelLeger yes i want all ids in one table, i know there will be one to one relationship but how i can call all values in main table.

Comment: @iMatt : you repeat what you said before, but do you want : 1/ Create a new table with all ids or 2/ Make a querie using those 3 ids to get information? I don't see the problem if you want to create a new table, just do it and add the data? We have no idea how each of those 3 ids works together so you have to be more precise in this case. If you need a query, I will repeat myself but you need to add relationship between those table so you can use those 3 ids

Comment: @MickaelLeger i want  Create a new table with all ids, i will define relationship later to extract data.

Comment: Please see my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create tables as follows,

```
 create table subject(subject_id int primary key,sub_name varchar(20))
 create table teacher(teacher_id int primary key,teacher_name varchar(20))
 create table class(class_id int primary key,class_sec varchar(20))

 create table timetable(t_id int primary key,subject_id int references 
 subject(subject_id)
 ,teacher_id int references teacher(teacher_id),class_id int references 
 class(class_id))
```

> Inserting sample values

```
 insert into subject values(1,'Tamil')
 insert into teacher values(1,'Pugal')
 insert into class values(1,'12th A')
 insert into timetable values(1,1,1,1)
```

> Using Inner join to connect tables,

```
 select s.sub_name,t.teacher_name,c.class_sec from timetable t1 
 inner join subject s
 on s.subject_id = t1.subject_id inner join teacher t
 on t.teacher_id = t1.teacher_id inner join class c
 on c.class_id   = t1.class_id
```

> Try this...And revert me if any clarifications needed..

Comment: yes it's on right direction, thankyou, as you mentioned to use;
 **insert into timetable values(1,1,1,1)**
i want these values (1,1,1) from each table automatically extracted, because if i have 1000 records i can't copy three thousand values from three tables to recall them in timetable.

Comment: For that you simply go for trigger concept . Trigger provides results for your expectations of automatically insert values.

Comment: i am sure it would be a simple query using foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Teachers.teacher_name, Class.class_sec, Subjects.subject_name FROM timetable
INNER JOIN Teachers ON Teachers.teacher_id = timetable.teacher_id
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.class_id = timetable.class_id
INNER JOIN Subjects ON Subjects.subject_id = timetable.subject_id
```

Comment: as i want to get only id, so i modified your code like this;
**SELECT Teachers.teacher_id FROM teachers
INNER JOIN Teachers ON Teachers.teacher_id = timetable.teacher_id;
SELECT class.class_id FROM class
INNER JOIN class ON class.class_id = timetable.class_id;
SELECT subjects.subject_id FROM subjects
INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id = timetable.subject_id**
--------
error:
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'class'

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to do. You can edit the first line to this: **SELECT Teachers.teacher_id, Class.class_id, Subjects.subject_id FROM timetable**

Comment: But the result would be the same like **SELECT * FROM timetable**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, and please correct me if I am wrong,
A class has a teacher, simplifying, a teacher teaches one class or more(the more complex case is more than once teacher per class):
The relation is 1 to many, so the *class* table should hold a teacher_id

A student can take more than one class, but there are many students in a class, then relationship is many-to-many,
a new table should be created class_per_student

We need to populate them with the relevant info of course,

Once that is done, we can join all relevant tables and get the timetables

Add the teacher_id column:

```
ALTER TABLE class ADD COLUMN teacher_id INT(9) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE class ADD KEY teacher_id (teacher_id);
```

Create a many-to-many table

```
CREATE TABLE class_per_student (
 id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 class_id INT(9) NOT NULL,
 student_id INT(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY id (id),
 KEY class_id (class_id),
 KEY student_id (student_id)
);
```

The time table select:

```
SELECT
 cps.class_id,
 cps.student_id,
 c.teacher_id
FROM
 class_per_student cps
 INNER JOIN class c ON c.id = cps.class_d
;
```

Notice that since the relationship between all entities is many-to-many, each of them (class, teacher, student) will appear more than once, BUT the unique combination of the 3 will appear once